# How to create data whenever thruDate is null in prisma upsert

Tags: node.js, postgresql, prisma

I am trying to create data whenever thruDate is null using upsert method, I added a condition on where.

```
const likeOrUnlikeOnPost = async (userId: string, postId: string) => {
  return await prisma.$transaction(async txc => {
    await prisma.postLikes.upsert({
      create: { userId, postId },
      update: { thruDate: new Date() },
      where: { userId_postId: { userId, postId }, thruDate: null },
    });
  });
};
```

but I am getting this error, I understand what the error is about. But how can I fix this? How can I create data whenever thruDate is null using prisma upsert?

```
 error: PrismaClientKnownRequestError: 
  Invalid `prisma.postLikes.upsert()` invocation:
  
  
  Unique constraint failed on the fields: (`userId`,`postId`)
      at si.handleRequestError (/home/fathe/Desktop/social-app/social-app-backend/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:125:6817)
      at si.handleAndLogRequestError (/home/fathe/Desktop/social-app/social-app-backend/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:125:6151)
      at si.request (/home/fathe/Desktop/social-app/social-app-backend/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:125:5859)
      at l (/home/fathe/Desktop/social-app/social-app-backend/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:130:9805) {
    code: 'P2002',
    clientVersion: '5.8.1',
    meta: { modelName: 'postLikes', target: [Array] }
  }
}
```

This is my prisma model:

```
model postLikes {
  userId   String
  postId   String
  shareId  String?
  fromDate DateTime  @default(now())
  thruDate DateTime?

  user            user             @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userPosts       userPosts        @relation(fields: [postId], references: [id])
  userSharedPosts userSharedPosts? @relation(fields: [shareId], references: [id])

  @@id([userId, postId])
}
```